# how to use make to generate a .tar.gz file?

Tags: makefile, tar

I'm searching for a way to *simplify* the way I work on projects. so i was wondering, is there a way to use a `Makefile` to generate and update a *.tar.gz* file of the entire project?

#### edit

i'm working on **C** solutions

Comment: @DevSolar actually I'm working on C solutions.. i forget to mention that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err... something like this?

```
project.tar.gz: $(FILELIST)
    tar uzf $@ $^
```

Rough, untested, about as precise as your question. Adjust to unvoiced requirements as appropriate. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and clean makefile example can be used.Simply add the directory or file names you want to tar to FILES_TO_TAR

```
HEADERS = header.h
FILES_TO_TAR = README.txt main.c header.h

default:
    gcc main.c $(HEADERS) -o output_name

clean:
    -rm -f *.o
cleanall:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f output_name
cleanandtar:
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f output_name
    tar -zcvf YOUR_TAR_NAME.tar.gz $(FILES_TO_TAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you also compress using the maximum compression setting for the final release (assuming that you’re publishing). On a modern computer it shouldn’t take that much more and it’s easy to set via the -9 flag